# Oracle - Guardando a coluna de uma consulta SQL em variavel NODEJS

Tags: node.js, oracle11g

> var oracledb = require('oracledb'); var rows = [4];
>
> oracledb.getConnection({   user: "",   password: "",   connectString:
> "" },  function (err, connection) {    connection.execute(
> `SELECT * FROM TMHML.SC5010 C5 WHERE  C5.C5_NUM = '000001' AND C5.C5_FILIAL = '01001'`,
> [],
> function(err, result) {
> if (err) {
> console.error(err.message);
> return;
> }
> for(let i of result.rows) {
> console.log(i[2]);
> }        connection.close();   }); });

Quero pegar, por exemplo, rows[1],somente oque tiver nela, na consulta.
tentei fazer de diversas formas, mas desisti kk, se alguém puder me ajudar...

Answer (score 0):

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb'); var rows = [4];

oracledb.getConnection({   user: "",   password: "",   connectString: "" },  function (err, connection) {    connection.execute(
    `SELECT * FROM TMHML.SC5010 C5 WHERE 
    C5.C5_NUM = '000001' AND C5.C5_FILIAL = '01001'`,
    [],  
    function(err, result) {  
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
      }    
      for(let i of result.rows) {
        console.log(i[2]);
      }        connection.close();   }); });
```

Comment: Maycon, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Adicionou esta resposta como uma resposta mesmo ou complemento à sua pergunta original? Se for um complemento, você pode editar sua pergunta ao invés de adicionar um post a mais como resposta.